# Laravel hasOne relationship returning null on dd

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I am going to try and write this question clearly, as in the past I haven't received any useful answers. People seem to think that my Auth::user() is null, or I am setting something up wrong. I can assure you that isn't the case.

I recently coded an application in **Laravel 5.3** and now have started scratch on **Laravel 5.4** and I am trying to get a simple hasOne relationship to work.

I have a table called `srp_user_statistics` which holds a record for each record in table `users`, it holds the statistics for that user. The primary key in table `users` is `id` and the primary key in table `srp_user_statistics` is `user_id`

I am trying to get the users record in table `srp_user_statistics` where `user_id` equals the column `id`in table `users` so in this case `Auth::user()->id`

This relationship worked perfectly in Laravel 5.3, but it seems to not be working in Laravel 5.4. I'll list below the things I have checked, to avoid people assuming things like the previous questions I have asked on other forum sites.

**Auth::user() is NOT null, it has 44 attributes when doing:**
`dd(Auth::user());`

**How do I know the relationship is null? How am I checking it?**
So at first, I check it by trying to print a column using `{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->user_id }}` in my blade view `home.blade.php` when doing this I am greeted with an error page by laravel stating that `Trying to get property of non-object`

**How do you know it isn't just that column?**

I did `dd(Auth::user()->roleplay)` and it returned `null`

Here is my Player.php, the class that controls table `user`

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Frontend\User;

use Hash;
use Eloquent;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authentication;

class Player extends Eloquent implements Authentication
{
    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    protected $table        = 'users';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['username'] = $value;
    }

    public function roleplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my Roleplay.php, the class that controls table `srp_user_statistics`

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Frontend\User;

use Eloquent;

class Roleplay extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'user_id';
    protected $table        = 'srp_user_statistics';
    public $timestamps      = true;
    protected $guarded = ['user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Frontend\User\Player', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function government_role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Frontend\Roleplay\GovernmentRole', 'government_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the error log when it displays `Trying to get property of non-object`

```
in HomeController.php line 16
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\\rcms_r\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Frontend\\User\\HomeController.php', 16, array()) in HomeController.php line 16
at HomeController->getView()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(HomeController), 'getView'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('getView', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(HomeController), 'getView') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

**What else have I tried?**
I have tried changing the relationships parameters, removing, adding and modifying them but it seems nothing will make this relationship work.

Comment: Okay, are you absolutely sure there is a Roleplay connected to the user inserted in the DB? What is the result of `$r = Roleplay::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()`?

Comment: That code returns a whole row, along with the data for that record, I have made a gist with the content as it is too much to post here.https://gist.github.com/Seriosk/0ccec7a3930ed72077b7e39cfa706df4

Comment: Yeah that seems fine. Has to be something with your relationship.

Comment: Alright one more thing I woud try for further debugging this. Try this `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $rp = Auth::user()->rolaplay; dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`. This should die dump all the queries executed (in this case the relationship query).

Comment: This simply returns `[]` and nothing more.

Comment: Then try like this: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $rp = Auth::user()->load('roleplay'); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` Btw I misspelled rolAplay in my last comment. If you just copy pasted it that could be the problem.

Comment: Yes I correctly spelt it, don't worry. On the new code it returns a RelationshipNotFoundException: `Call to undefined relationship [roleplay] on model [App\User].`

Comment: Well that's the problem then.`Auth::user();` returns App\User and not App\Database\Frontend\User\Player as you expect it to. Check config/auth.php. I think you need to replace the value (in the auth config) in providers.users.model from App\User to your model. I've never done this, so this is a wild guess :) keep me updated if that works.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this, I just wish it was an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the relationship should be defined like this:

```
public function roleplay()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Frontend\User\Roleplay', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Change `role_id` to the actual name of the foreign key you use in the `players` table.

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the  Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method.
>
> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's id column in the user_id column of the Phone record. If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the hasOne method specifying your custom key.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: I changed my relationship in class 'Player' to what you have put, replacing `role_id` with `id` (Identifier for table `users`) but it hasn't changed anything. I still get a null array returned.

Comment: column `id` is what I use to identify records in my `users` table, is that not the column I should be putting? that is the only column I have in my users table that represents the identifier for a record. It would help if you went in to detail more.

Comment: `dd(Auth::user()->roleplay);` still returns null, even with the updated code.